Linear PDF Approximation
I am trying to estimate the shape parameter alpha of the PDF of a Pareto distribution, given that I have incomplete data. Specifically, the true dataset spans values between 10 and 50, but my observed data only covers the range from 25 to 50 (i.e., I am missing all data between 10 and 25). My challenge is recovering the correct value of alpha, given this missing data.
Background
A Pareto distribution is defined by two parameters:

alpha (the shape parameter, which determines the slope of the tail), and
xmin (the minimum value of the distribution).

If I attempt to fit a Pareto distribution directly to the observed data, there are two issues:

If I set xmin = 10 (the true minimum), the fit is invalid because my data does not include values below 25 and the alpha is incorrect.
If I set xmin = 25 (the minimum of my observed data), the estimated alpha is incorrect because it doesn’t account for the missing portion of the data.

Key Insight
A key property of the Pareto distribution is that its probability density function (PDF), when plotted in log-log space log10(x) vs. log10(y), forms a straight line. The slope of this line is related to the shape parameter alpha by:
slope = -(alpha + 1)
This property suggests that even with a large section of the data missing, I might still recover alpha by transforming my observed data into log-log space, fitting a straight line to the resulting points, and using the slope to compute alpha.
The Problem
The difficulty lies in constructing the PDF for the observed data. Since I only have a vector of data values, I don’t directly have a PDF (or density values). This basically means that if I were to attempt to construct a straight line to recover alpha, I have x but do not have y. To approximate the density, I’ve attempted the following:

Use kernel density estimation (via R’s density() function) to generate a smooth approximation of the PDF.

Transform both the x-values (data) and y-values (density estimates) into log10 space, fit a line to the result, and use the slope to estimate alpha.


Here's an example of the kernel density approach, but I'm not wedded to it.
# Simulated observed data
set.seed(123)
data <- rpareto(1000, alpha = 2, xmin = 10)  # True data
observed_data <- data[data >= 25]            # Truncate to observed range

# Estimate density using kernel smoothing
density_est <- density(observed_data, from = 25, to = 50)
log_x <- log10(density_est$x)
log_y <- log10(density_est$y)

# Fit a linear model in log-log space
lm_fit <- lm(log_y ~ log_x)

# Extract slope and compute alpha
slope <- coef(lm_fit)[2]
alpha_est <- -slope - 1

alpha_est

Questions

Is there a more principled or robust method to approximate the PDF for the observed data in this context, particularly one that accounts for the missing data?
Is there a way to approximate the linear PDF at all? I know it doesn't really exist, but is there a workaround?
Are there any theoretical or practical pitfalls in using kernel density estimation for this purpose?



I assume when you talk about taking logs of both "x" and "y" "of the pdf" you're talking about y being histogram counts or something similar. You should be more explicit from the start about what your data consist of. 2. It's not clear to me why (i) missingness would be problematic per se (though MNAR would be an issue), nor (ii) why taking logs would solve whatever problem there is (at least in a way that couldn't be solved without doing this). Did you instead mean that there was truncation or perhaps even censoring? If so, please describe the nature of this "not-observing" clearly


In short, please assume we don't know what's in your head (which I assure you, we really don't), and begin by giving more context.

Re the edit: the method implemented in your code has little to do with the problem you articulate at the outset, leaving us wondering what you're really trying to ask.  What is the basic statistical question you wish to pose?  Is it about fitting Pareto distributions, about estimating distributions generally (aka "approximating the pdf"), about KDE, or something else altogether?

The core statistical question I am asking is: How can I accurately estimate the shape parameter of a Pareto distribution when I only have partial data? I thought a way around the problem is if I eschewed fitting a Pareto distribution altogether and instead used KDE to approximate densities for my data, which can then be put into logspace and fit with a linear model to get alpha for the Pareto without ever having to fit the Pareto distribution itself. So KDE is the method I've tried to avoid fitting the Pareto to partial data, and I'm wondering if there's a better way

The KDE method works off the assumption that both the Pareto fitting and the KDE both provide estimates of density for every value of x, but the KDE method doesn't require pre-known parameters. So my thought was that I can kind of circumvent the Pareto by approximating density with the KDE. But I'm positive there's a better way

Let's start with the most basic part of this situation: why are the data missing?

It's a limitation of how the data were collected. Measurement tool A only measures the data down to 25 in this example, and I want to see if I can extrapolate the rest of the distribution from it. I also have, separately, the real world measurements from 10 to 50 so I know what the exact distribution should look like, alpha and all. However, the point of the exercise is to figure out the best method of extrapolating alpha from measurement tool A alone, which I compare to the known data to see if it got close. Assume that finding a different measurement tool is outside the scope of the problem

This sounds like (left) censored data and your objective sounds like estimating the distribution.  You have dropped one useful piece of information: the count of values the measurement tool could not measure.  If you don't know that, then you have truncated data.  Searching our site for either of these terms in conjunction with "estimate" or "estimation" will turn up many techniques.  Check them out and let us know whether my interpretation of your problem is correct.
